# move multiple elements with raphael javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I'm creating an image tagging ability for a CMS using Raphael javascript based on one of the examples given on the Raphael website (curver example). It works by letting the user add arrows (paths) and labels (text) to images and move them around to mark structures in the image ("points of interest"). I've got it working for one path pr. label ([jsfiddle.net/nartex1234/9m5d7fqd/](http://jsfiddle.net/nartex1234/9m5d7fqd/)), but struggling to make it work for more than one path pr. label ([jsfiddle.net/nartex1234/wm1odgtz/](http://jsfiddle.net/nartex1234/wm1odgtz/)).

I feel it all comes down to the limit of my programming skills. I really donæt know how to grasp the solution. I've included the code for the working example below. Any suggestions or hints on how to get this working is most welcome.

```js
// Create canvas
var R = Raphael(0, 0, "100%", "100%");

// This is the style objects for the article labels
var labelattr = {
  font: "30px Helvetica",
  "font-weight": "bold",
  opacity: 0.9,
  fill: "#fff",
  "stroke-width": 1,
  stroke: "#000"
};

var discattr = {
  fill: "#f0f",
  stroke: "none",
  opacity: 0.3 // normaly set to 0.01 so that it is not visible
};

var arrowattr = {
  "stroke-width": 3,
  "stroke-linecap": "round",
  "arrow-end": "classic -wide"
};

// The JSON data object (normally provided via AJAX from a database)
var data = [{
  "label": "Red",
  "articlelabelid": "12",
  "labelid": "28",
  "x1": "400",
  "y1": "150",
  "pois": [{
    "articlelabelid": "12",
    "poid": "3",
    "x2": "300",
    "y2": "400"
  }]
}, {
  "label": "Yellow",
  "articlelabelid": "13",
  "labelid": "30",
  "x1": "300",
  "y1": "500",
  "pois": [{
    "articlelabelid": "13",
    "poid": "4",
    "x2": "400",
    "y2": "600"
  }, {
    "articlelabelid": "13",
    "poid": "5",
    "x2": "450",
    "y2": "600"
  }, {
    "articlelabelid": "13",
    "poid": "6",
    "x2": "200",
    "y2": "500"
  }]
}, {
  "label": "Blue",
  "articlelabelid": "14",
  "labelid": "29",
  "x1": "700",
  "y1": "450",
  "pois": [{
    "articlelabelid": "14",
    "poid": "13",
    "x2": "900",
    "y2": "800"
  }, {
    "articlelabelid": "14",
    "poid": "14",
    "x2": "800",
    "y2": "700"
  }]
}, {
  "label": "Black",
  "articlelabelid": "15",
  "labelid": "31",
  "x1": "100",
  "y1": "100",
  "pois": [{
    "articlelabelid": "15",
    "poid": "15",
    "x2": "200",
    "y2": "200"
  }]
}];


// The start, move and up functions
function start() {}

function move(dx, dy) {
  this.update(dx - (this.dx || 0), dy - (this.dy || 0));
  this.dx = dx;
  this.dy = dy;
}

function up() {
  this.dx = this.dy = 0;
  switch (this.type) {
    case "text":
      x = this.attr("x"), y = this.attr("y"), objclass = 'articlelabel_' + this.node.id;
      break;
    case "circle":
      x = this.attr("cx"), y = this.attr("cy"), objclass = 'poi_' + this.node.id;
      break;
  }
}



// Function to draw the labels and lines, but only the first line/poi (point of interest) in the object
function labeline(object) {
  // Find coordinates of label
  var x = parseInt(object.x1, 10);
  var y = parseInt(object.y1, 10);
  // Number of pois (points of interest) for this label
  var poi_count = Object.keys(object.pois).length;

  var ax = parseInt(object['pois'][0]['x2'], 10);
  var ay = parseInt(object['pois'][0]['y2'], 10);
  var label = object.label;
  var articlelabelid = object.articlelabelid;
  var poid = object['pois'][0]['poid'];

  // The path - creates an array with two arrays within it
  var path = [
      ["M", x, y],
      ["L", ax, ay]
    ],


    // The set
    controls = R.set(
      R.path(path).attr(arrowattr), // Controls [0]
      R.circle(ax, ay, 9).attr(discattr), // Controls [1]
      R.text(x, y, label).attr(labelattr) // Controls [2]
    );

  controls[2].update = function(x, y) {
    this.node.id = articlelabelid;
    var X = this.attr("x") + x,
      Y = this.attr("y") + y;
    this.attr({
      x: X,
      y: Y
    });
    path[0][1] = X;
    path[0][2] = Y;
    controls[0].attr({
      path: path
    });
  };
  controls[1].update = function(x, y) {
    this.node.id = poid;
    var X = this.attr("cx") + x,
      Y = this.attr("cy") + y;
    this.attr({
      cx: X,
      cy: Y
    });
    path[1][1] = X;
    path[1][2] = Y;
    controls[0].attr({
      path: path
    });
  };
  controls.drag(move, start, up);
}

// Run function for every label in the JSON data object
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  labeline(data[i]);
}
```

Comment: I think you need to break the problem down further with a smaller concise example in code. There's probably just a bit too much code to delve through.

Comment: You're probably right. I'll try to work with the code some more to work out the bits and pieces I can't figure out how to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it works. It all came down to using for loops for every point. I've integrated this script with my CMS and it now works like it should (adding and saving label and arrow positions in a database). I include the script if anyone finds it useful. Heres is the updated JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nartex1234/wm1odgtz/

```
// Create canvas
var R = Raphael(0, 0, "100%", "100%");

// This is the style objects for the article labels
var labelattr = {
    font: "30px Helvetica",
        "font-weight": "bold",
    opacity: 0.9,
    fill: "#fff",
        "stroke-width": 1,
    stroke: "#000"
};

var discattr = {
    fill: "#f0f",
    stroke: "none",
    opacity: 0.3 // normaly set to 0.01 so that it is not visible
};

var arrowattr = {
    "stroke-width": 3,
        "stroke-linecap": "round",
        "arrow-end": "classic -wide"
};

// The JSON data object (normally provided via AJAX from a database)
var data = [{
    "label": "Red",
        "articlelabelid": "12",
        "labelid": "28",
        "x1": "400",
        "y1": "150",
        "pois": [{
        "articlelabelid": "12",
            "poid": "3",
            "x2": "300",
            "y2": "400"
    }]
}, {
    "label": "Yellow",
        "articlelabelid": "13",
        "labelid": "30",
        "x1": "300",
        "y1": "500",
        "pois": [{
        "articlelabelid": "13",
            "poid": "4",
            "x2": "400",
            "y2": "600"
    }, {
        "articlelabelid": "13",
            "poid": "5",
            "x2": "450",
            "y2": "600"
    }, {
        "articlelabelid": "13",
            "poid": "6",
            "x2": "200",
            "y2": "500"
    }]
}, {
    "label": "Blue",
        "articlelabelid": "14",
        "labelid": "29",
        "x1": "700",
        "y1": "450",
        "pois": [{
        "articlelabelid": "14",
            "poid": "13",
            "x2": "900",
            "y2": "800"
    }, {
        "articlelabelid": "14",
            "poid": "14",
            "x2": "800",
            "y2": "700"
    }]
}, {
    "label": "Black",
        "articlelabelid": "15",
        "labelid": "31",
        "x1": "100",
        "y1": "100",
        "pois": [{
        "articlelabelid": "15",
            "poid": "15",
            "x2": "200",
            "y2": "200"
    }]
}];


// The start, move and up functions
function start() {}

function move(dx, dy) {
    this.update(dx - (this.dx || 0), dy - (this.dy || 0));
    this.dx = dx;
    this.dy = dy;
}

function up() {
    this.dx = this.dy = 0;
    switch (this.type) {
        case "text":
            x = this.attr("x"), y = this.attr("y")
            break;
        case "circle":
            x = this.attr("cx"), y = this.attr("cy")
            break;
    }
}

// Make array of all paths and circles
function pointers(count, object, x, y) {
    var pointers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var ax = parseInt(object.pois[i].x2, 10);
        var ay = parseInt(object.pois[i].y2, 10);
        pointers[i] =
            [
                [ax, ay, 9],        /*POI [0] */    
                [                   /*PATH [1] */
                    ["M", x, y],
                    ["L", ax, ay]
                ]
            ]                   
        }
    return pointers;
}




// This works for one pois pr. label, but not multiple pois pr label or labels without poi
function labeline(object) {
    // Find coordinates of label
    var x = parseInt(object.x1, 10);
    var y = parseInt(object.y1, 10);
    // Number of pois (points of interest) for this label
    var poi_count = Object.keys(object.pois).length;

    // Label variables from objevt
    var label = object.label;
    var articlelabelid = object.articlelabelid;

    // Make array of all paths and circles
    var result = pointers(poi_count, object, x, y);

    // Makes new arrays for paths and controls
    var path = [];
    var controls = [];  

    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        // Adds paths to the path array
        path[i] = result[i][1];

        // The set
        controls[i] = R.set(
            R.path(path[i]).attr(arrowattr), // Controls [0]
            R.circle(result[i][0][0], result[i][0][1], result[i][0][2]).attr(discattr)//, // Controls [1]
        );
        // Sets the key of the controls as a 'parentkey' property of the child array and the id of the point of interest as the node id
        controls[i][1].parentkey = i;
        controls[i][1].node.id = 'poi_' + object.pois[i].poid;

        // Updating the correct path
        controls[i][1].update = function (x, y) {
            var X = this.attr("cx") + x,
                Y = this.attr("cy") + y;
            this.attr({
                cx: X,
                cy: Y
            });
            path[this.parentkey][1][1] = X;
            path[this.parentkey][1][2] = Y;
            controls[this.parentkey][0].attr({
                path: path[this.parentkey]
            });
        };
        controls[i].drag(move, start, up);      
    }

    // The label
    label = R.text(x, y, label).attr(labelattr);
    label.node.id = 'articlelabel_' + articlelabelid;
    label.update = function (x, y) {
        var X = this.attr("x") + x,
            Y = this.attr("y") + y;
        this.attr({
            x: X,
            y: Y
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
            path[i][0][1] = X;
            path[i][0][2] = Y;
            controls[i][0].attr({
                path: path[i]
            });
        }
    };
    label.drag(move, start, up);
}

// Run function for every label in the JSON data object
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    labeline(data[i]);
}
```